# How to handle Forms with Phoenix LiveView

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have a form in phoenix which looks like this

```
<%= form_for @changeset, Routes.post_path(@conn, :create, @post), [method: "post", multipart: true], fn f -> %>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="form-group col-6">
      <%= input f, :title, "Title", [class: "form-control", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Title", required: true] %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-6">
     <%= input f, :description, "Description", [class: "form-control", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Description", required: true] %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex mt-3">
   <%= submit "Create Post" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The above form works fine, Now I want to change this form to implement LiveView. So I have done something like this

```
<%= form_for @changeset, "#", [method: "post", multipart: true], fn f -> %>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="form-group col-6">
      <%= input f, :title, "Title", [class: "form-control", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Title", required: true] %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-6">
     <%= input f, :description, "Description", [class: "form-control", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Description", required: true] %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex mt-3">
   <button phx-click="create-post" phx-value="form-value">Create Post"</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am confused in the place of `form-value`, what needs to be send so that I will get the correct form data which contains `title` and `description` in my `handle_event` function.

I tried passing the `@changeset` and also `f`, but they are sending proper `phx-value` which will contain my `title` and `description`.

Not sure, If am implementing Form with LiveView correctly or It needs to be done in different manner.

Answer (score 3):

The only once difference here is that you don't want to use an anonymous function with form_for.

```
<%= form_for @changeset, "#", [phx_submit: "post", multipart: true], fn f -> %>
...
<% end %>
```

becomes

```
<%= f = form_for @changeset, "#", [phx_submit: "post", multipart: true] %>
...
</form>
```

Anonymous function content can't be diffed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to implement the form with phoenix liveview

```
<%= form_for @changeset, "#", [phx_submit: "post", multipart: true], fn f -> %>
  <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="form-group col-6">
        <%= input f, :title, "Title", [class: "form-control", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Title", required: true] %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-6">
       <%= input f, :description, "Description", [class: "form-control", type: "text", placeholder: "Enter Description", required: true] %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex mt-3">
      <%= submit "Create Post", phx_disable_with: "Posting..." %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```